# SQL query distinct - group by

Tags: sql

I am having issues with a sql query.

I have following table (I simplified it a bit):

```
 ChainId    ComponentId    TransmitEndpointId
   1            156               NULL
   1            156               7
   1            157               7
   2            510               6
   2            510               6
   2            511               6
   2            511               8
```

What I need to do is get the number of TransmitEndpointId's foreach 'unique' ComponentId in a 'unique' ChainId.
So the result of the above data would be: 5 (2 unique componentId's in Chain 1 & 2 unique componentId's in Chain 2 with 2 different TransmitId's ==> NULL values don't count)

This is quite complex and have no idea on how to start with this query.

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the  `where TransmitEndpointId is not null` or you will get a 0 because of the NULL

```
SELECT ChainId,
       ComponentId,
       count(distinct TransmitEndpointId)
FROM chain
where TransmitEndpointId is not null
GROUP BY ChainId, ComponentId

select sum(endPointNr) from 
(
SELECT count(distinct TransmitEndpointId) as     endPointNr
FROM chain
where TransmitEndpointId is not null
GROUP BY ChainId, ComponentId
) X
```

[image]

EDIT (why add  `TransmitEndpointId is not null`)

[image]

Comment: count(columnname) will not count NULL values it does an implicit "where ... is not null" (At least that's what the SQL standard requires)

Comment: yes but if you only have 1 combination of ChainID and ComponentID with NULL, you will get a zero value and I dont think the OP wants that

Comment: see my edit. Its fine when you have more than one record with values for chainID X ComponentID, the problem is when you have only one with NULL

Comment: Correct, but that zero value wouldn't change the overall sum (which is what the OP ultimately wants). But it's definitely worth pointing out

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the unique count for each ChainID/ComponentId combination.

```
SELECT ChainId,
       ComponentId,
       count(distinct TransmitEndpointId)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY ChainId, ComponentId
```

Now you can use that inside a derived table to get the total count:

```
SELECT sum(distinct_count)
FROM  (
  SELECT ChainId,
         ComponentId,
         count(distinct TransmitEndpointId) as distinct_count
  FROM your_table
  GROUP BY ChainId, ComponentId
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is what you want

Please Try this code

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ChainId,ComponentId,TransmitEndpointId)
FROM your_table
WHERE TransmitEndpointId IS NOT NULL
```